# What are the drawbacks to duplicating a class in different namespaces?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class called [SimpleCommand](https://gist.github.com/773312).  It is a single file class that implements ICommand in a very simple way (hence the name).

I am finding that I am putting it several of my projects.  (I just copy the code and add it into the project.)

These projects are all in the same solution and resulting wpf application.

My question is: **Aside from increasing the size of my DLLs by a bit, what are the drawbacks to copying this code around?**

(I am trying to decide if it is worth the work to put it in a nuget package.)

NOTE: I have not changed this code in years, and I don't plan to.

Comment: I have found that a surprising amount of code that I don't plan to ever change eventually does change.

Comment: Is there a special reason you are considering the nuget package? What about simply creating a dedicated project and putting the `SimpleCommand` there? When you need to use it, you simply reference the project.

Comment: @EricJ. - and if that happens then a find/replace would allow a quick update of the changes...  (Or I could go to a nuget package at that time)  Right?

Comment: Why don't you put it in a single library shared by your various projects. Generally speaking, maintenance is an issue, but you haven't changed it in years. I generally have a library of routines I reuse between projects because it's simpler to maintain and doesn't require copy and paste every time I create a new project.

Comment: Why are you looking at putting it a nuget package?  Why not just have a utility assembly that contains this class and anything else that's shared among projects?

Comment: @NikolaAnusev - good point.  I guess I am not doing that because my solution is so big that I usually start new stuff in a separate location then add it in later.  Still, I could copy the dll over...

Comment: @Vaccano: Depends on how extensively your common code is used.  I find that little classes and utilities tend to get reused in many of my projects, so I put all of them in a library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here isn't that there are various classes with the same name in different namespaces.

The issue is that you're duplicating code, which is really bad idea.

If you want to expand your SimpleCommand to ABitMoreComplexCommand you end up copying it all over.

If you need to compare one command to another by type you couldn't do that reliably - heuristics you may implement could give you false positives

Bottom line: make another project, put all reusable code there, don't copy it around

Comment: OK, sounds right.  I have 79 projects in my solution already... I guess one more won't hurt.

Comment: Really? 79 projects in your solution? I can't imagine a situation where that's a good idea...

Comment: Chances are your solution can be greatly refactored and optimized but in real business environments management holds the existing structure dear and would rather grow it than shrink it

Comment: @Pete Me neither, but I used to work on an "enterprise" app which consisted of a solution that had, at one time, over 90 projects. Good ideas are not always brought to life :)

Comment: @Pete - We are creating an enterprise level WPF Prism application.  Prism likes things in separate projects.  We have also found that the loosely coupled modularity also helps with maintenance, so we have not fought the design.  (Though it does put a strain on Visual Studio.)

Comment: Having lots of modules isn't necessarily a problem. I've worked on projects with far more than that. Having them all in a single solution is what seems like a bad idea. You mention the strain on Visual Studio. There's also the fact that it makes navigating the Solution Explorer a nightmare.

Answer (score 2):

Copying and pasting is the most innefficient way of reusing code, IMO. What happens if you ever decide to add a simple bool property to this class? you will have to do it as many times as you ever copied and pasted it.

I suggest to group these reusable parts in a single DLL and reference them from multiple projects, instead.